# C# pass arguments to app when selected from context menu

Tags: c#, registry, command-line-arguments, contextmenu

I am trying to add an option to context menu using the below code

```
using var zipTargetRegKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\.zip\");
zipTargetRegKey.SetValue(string.Empty, "CompressedFolder");
zipTargetRegKey.SetValue("Content Type", "application/x-zip-compressed");
zipTargetRegKey.SetValue("DontCompressInPackage", string.Empty);
zipTargetRegKey.CreateSubKey("OpenWithProgids").SetValue("CompressedFolder", string.Empty);
zipTargetRegKey.CreateSubKey("PersistentHandler").SetValue(string.Empty, "098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb");

using var regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Software\Classes\.zip\shell\AppName\");
regKey.SetValue(string.Empty, "Unzip");
regKey.SetValue("Icon", "icon_path");
regKey.CreateSubKey("command").SetValue(string.Empty, "path_to_exe.exe %1"));
```

The icon and option in the context menu shows up just fine, however, no arguments are being passed to my application. I also tried using `"%1"` or `"%~1"`, but none seems to work.

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Follow up: Can I pass custom arguments? Like path_to_exe.exe /custom_arg %1